# NPM package aliases and Typescript definition files

Tags: typescript, npm, alias

I have a package that I need in two separate versions - luckily, as of npm 6.9.0 I can achieve that [pretty easily](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0001-package-aliases.md#detailed-explanation).

The question is: the package has type definitions. But, if I create an alias for that package, i refer to it by the alias created - and the typings are not automatically detected because the name is changed. How can I achieve so it's auto-detected?

Answer (score 3):

One solution I've come up with is copying `@types/package-name` into `@types/package-alias`, run after postinstall npm script. Maybe it'll get automated overtime.

EDIT: The better approach would be to just install `@types` in specified version, aliased as well.

`npm install @types/package-alias@npm:@types/package@1.0.0`

Comment: Is there a suggest approach on how to address this when the typing are bundles with the package?